# How can I reindex a string?

Tags: php, arrays, string, indexing

It basically comes down to this. I have a string called $name. $name usually has the value ''blablabla'', the value comes from an external resource so that's why it's encapsulated in two single quotes. If i would declare this variable myself it would look like this: 
`$name = "''blablabla''";`

I am deleting these single quotes by:

```
$name[0] = '';
$name[1] = '';
$name[mb_strlen($name, 'UTF-8')-1] = '';
$name[mb_strlen($name, 'UTF-8')-2] = '';
```

(unsetting the string with a index doesn't work)
So now I have $name with value "blablabla" without the signle quotes.
Here's my problem. 
When I look at the source code, there are strange characters before the "blablabla".
How can I deal with this? 
And, is there any way to reindex my string (for example what array_values does for arrays)?

**EDIT** 
Eventually I used this code :

```
$name = mb_substr($name, 2, -2, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$name = "''foo''";

$name = substr($name, 2, -2);

echo $name; # foo
```

1. You're dealing with encodings, while the characters in question (`'`) are single-byte. Strings in PHP are still binary only, which means, you can just cut it off at the ends.
2. When you unset using the index, keep in mind that it's the binary position. `mb_strlen` does not suit to gather the binary index position, `strlen` does:

.

```
$name = "''foo''";

$name[0] = '';
$name[1] = '';

$len = strlen($name); # binary safe string length

$name[$len-1] = '';
$name[$len-2] = '';

echo $name; # foo
```

### `mb_strlen` compared with `strlen`

```
$utf8 = 'ä';
mb_strlen($utf8, 'UTF-8'); # 1
strlen($utf8);             # 2

$utf8[1] != 'ä';
```

Comment: What do you mean characters in question are single-byte? I said that the values come from an external resource. So it can be multi-byte. That's why I use the mb functions of PHP.
Btw, thnx for you answer, i don't want to be rude but I'm only saying why I use the mb functions.

Comment: No it's okay to support multi-byte character sets. If the string is UTF-8 (as you wrote), the `'` is a single byte. So you can savely remove them with the concrete byte offset, but you need the byte-offset gathered with strlen as only strlen will return the correct value in this case.

Comment: So you're saying that mb_strlen wouldn't work ? I don't understand why then.

Comment: I added a comparison below. Please see for what mb_strlen works and for what not.

Comment: hakre, you should use $utf8[0] which is that weird looking a

Comment: @orhan: neither `[0]` nor `[1]` is that `ä` character.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Trim function:

```
$name = trim($name, "'");
echo $name; // Prints: blablabla
```